# How to delay a javascript onclick function to not continue running unless the click is completed on the item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically how can I make it that my javascript function only runs when the user completes a click on it, and not run if a user clicks and holds on the item, then releases their mouse away from the item.

**JS :**

```
var foosetter = function (param)
{
    var urlset = param.getAttribute("src");
    $('#selectedFooImg').attr("src", urlset);
};
```

**HTML :**

```
<img onclick="foosetter(this)" src="assets/foo/foo1.png" class="fooimg" alt="Foo Image">
```

Comment: if you're only interested on the **mouseup** event, than instead of `click` use the `mouseup` event. (`onmouseup` if you use the not-so-great inline JS).

Comment: onclick shouldn't be fired if mouse button is released outside element. On which browser do you encounter this issue?

Comment: (Offtopic suggestion) `param` as term might be a bit confusing since function attributes can accept coffee, drugs and cookies, I suggest using i.e: `elem` since youre passing the HTMLImageElement Object.

Comment: If you **need** both events to be triggered, than you're cool, since `click` will not trigger if the actual click-release happened outside of the initial `click` event target element... Logically, therefore you should not run any function `onmousedown` :) Review your program logic.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If i'm correct, there was a bug in older IE version but if i'm still correct it was regarding dblclick, not click. Maybe that's kind of issue OP is referring but hard to say without more explaination

Comment: @A.Wolff (Nice catch) I'm quite sure OP missed some explanation and the exact Browser where the issue was registered as `click` instead ignored since of un-matching `event.target`s.

Comment: As you can see from this example you cannot register a click that runs a function if your *"mouse-release"* was not inside the element that registered the initial click: http://jsbin.com/wedelu/1/edit?html,css,js,output . If in your case that's what actually happens, **pelease provide a fully testable use-case.**

Answer (score 0):

The click event already achieves this functionality. Make sure the img area is  not larger than what you expect. You can also add draggable="false" so that the image cannot be dragged.

```js
$('.fooimg').click(function (param)
        {    console.log('it works');
            //var urlset = param.getAttribute("src");
            //$('#selectedFooImg').attr("src", urlset);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="assets/foo/foo1.png" class="fooimg" alt="Foo Image" draggable="false">
```

Comment: Ya but this is different behaviour than click on element

Comment: That's not how i understand expected behaviour. If OP wants to complete a click, he needs to use click event, not just mouseup. If his code doesn't work, then something wrong comes from somewhere else

Comment: `querySelector` on a series of `CLASS` elements makes no much use... probably (since it's also more probable that there are more than one class elements) is to use `querySelectorAll` or rather (to prevent IE8 incompatibilities with CSS3 selectors) to use jQuery -> since OP already uses jQuery :)

Answer (score -1):

Use mouseup()

```
$("div").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).after("Mouse button released.");
});
```

Comment: `just use mouseup` is already in the comments section. Here, can you please explain how does this "*delays*" a function execution?

Comment: I don't understand how this is answering question?! Now im really confused why this has been upvoted twice, really...